# Different TableView Styles in iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I just got the new SportsCenter app and I like the way their TableView looks on the Now section.  Is this some new option for TableView on iOS 7, or is this a custom built TableView?[image]

Comment: It most likely uses UITableViewCell subclassing to customise the appearance.

Comment: I just mainly like that each cell is separated and gives appearance of being raised above the background.  Much better than standard TableView look where in iOS 7, the line doesn't even go all the way across.

Comment: This also goes against the guidelines of iOS7. You are not strictly required to follow them, but your users expect consistency, and if you don't give it to them, they will vote with their wallets and low ranks. Like it or not, you should play nice with the iOS7 look.

Comment: Sorry @LeoNatan but you're wrong.  You ARE completely allowed to customize the look of a TableView.  Look at SportsCenter, look at Twitter, Facebook, etc.  Every app is not required to look the same, and that is why there are things that exist like Grouped Table View Cells.  You should just remove your comment as it is completely useless.

Comment: @user717452 I did not say you are not allowed to. I just said your users may not like it because they grow accustomed to something else. If you feel my comment is useless, you are welcome to report it.

Comment: You can achieve cell separation look like that by saying to the dataSource that your cell height will be that much bigger, by setting the cell backgroundColor to clear and drawing your cell subviews in an inset rect.

Comment: @ChuckKelly The only idiot here is the one insulting others because they disagree with their opinion.